# WSL: bash-cmd.exe interoperability: get rid of carriage return

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I assigned the windows' user name to a variable in WSL Ubuntu Bash with this command:

```
WINUSER=`cmd.exe /C 'echo %username%'`
```

If I echo the variable, it behaves normally:

```
$ echo $WINUSER
myusername
```

However, if I try to insert it into a string, every character I place AFTER the variable will replace the characters at the beginning of the string, like this:

```
echo "/mnt/c/User/$WINUSER/Documents"
/Documentsr/myusername
```

While, if I don't place characters after the strings:

```
echo "/mnt/c/User/$WINUSER"
/mnt/c/User/myusername
```

It prints correctly to stout, but I still can't `cd /mnt/c/User/$WINUSER`

Since it doesn't occur with other variables, such as $HOME, I guess it depends by the output of the windows-wsl inter-operability. How could I solve this?

Comment: I guess you have a carriage return at the end of the string returned from `cmd.exe`. What do you see for `printf '%q\n' "$WINUSER"`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I get `$'myusername\r'` in the shell output

Comment: It's a carriage return. You can get rid of it with something like `"${WINUSER//$'\r'}"` when you use the variable.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Also, thanks for posting a reference. That could definitely apply as duplicate to this question, feel free to cast a close vote.

Comment: I used the wrong duplicate at first, now I can't vote any longer :/